# Can I plot/filter just the peak value per day in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset which is amount (parts per million) against time (every minute)

I need to find the peak for each day, so that I can plot that against other data, I can manually do this using =MAX( but I have a lot of data points and I am sure there is a better way

Many Thanks for the help

[image: DataSet Example]

Comment: You might be able to use a pivot chart.

Comment: Maxifs() and a list of dates?

Comment: My list of dates would be 32 separate days, easier to just do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where and how you want show this data, but, if you want get a max value amount per day, you can try add an array formula, like that:

```
=MAX(IF($COL_DATES = $DAY, $COL_VALUE, 0))
```

Replace `$COL_DATES` to your column of day date, replace `$DAY` to value of day what you want get max value and replace `$COL_VALUE` to your column of values.

After press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>